# What does the [Bit 31:16] format mean, for example, in datasheet's

Tags: bit, binary-data, scientific-computing, digital, datasheet

Can someone help me understand what the format means: "Bit 31:16" (for example). It is the same format that appears on the electronic components data sheet.
So far I still can't understand what they mean ...

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It usually means bits positioned from 16 through 31 in a 32-bit register (or greater). If you would put the url for the datasheet, it might be possible to answer this more fully.

Comment: OK,
I said datasheet to try to be more practical, but in reality, it is an Intel document as I am working to learn how to edit BIOS (es). So you can see this link:
https://pdfslide.net/documents/spi-programming-guide.html
It is in the table on page 54.

Comment: It means the two high bytes, which are marked reserved in the table.